# Problema com categorias no Prestashop

Tags: php, e-commerce

Olá, gostaria da ajuda de alguém, estou com esse problema a dias e não ha pesquisa que resolvesse isso.

Estou testando uma ferramenta de importação de produtos no Prestashop, e depois de realizar alguns testes fui excluir os produtos, mas dessa vez resolvi deletar as categorias e consequentemente deletar os produtos (Prestashop fornecesse essa opção) só que depois que o fiz, quando acesso a pagina de produtos do painel recebo o seguinte erro:

```
[PrestaShopException]

Root category must be an integer value
at line 212 in file classes/helper/HelperTreeCategories.php

207.     }
208. 
209.     public function setRootCategory($value)
210.     {
211.         if (!Validate::isInt($value)) {
212.             throw new PrestaShopException('Root category must be an integer value');
213.         }
214. 
215.         $this->_root_category = $value;
216.         return $this;
217.     }

HelperTreeCategoriesCore->setRootCategory - [line 2504 - controllers/admin/AdminProductsController.php] - [1 Arguments]
AdminProductsControllerCore->initContent - [line 189 - classes/controller/Controller.php]
ControllerCore->run - [line 367 - classes/Dispatcher.php]
DispatcherCore->dispatch - [line 58 - admin/index.php]
```

[image: Tela com o erro]

Já procurei em diversos sites pela internet mas o problema não se resolve facilmente apenas criando uma categoria Root, ou estou fazendo a mesma de forma errônea.

[image: Lista de categorias existentes]

Estou usando o Prestashop 1.6.1.3

Answer (score 1):

Olá.

Isso ocorreu porque você apagou a categoria root(principal), ela não deve ser apagada. Para corrigir, crie uma nova categoria pelo painel do Prestashop (se não conseguir, crie diretamente no banco de dados), em seguida acesse a tabela de categoria no banco de dados (ex: "ps_category") e atribua o valor "1" na coluna "is_root_category".

Essa ação diz para o Prestashop qual é a nova categoria que deve ser tratada como root.

Answer (score 0):

Verifica se na base de dados na tabela *ps_category_lang* existe a categoria **raiz** com ID=1 e a categoria "Inicio" com id=2.

Se não existir vais ter que criar manualmente na base de dados.

**id_category** --> **Valor = 1**

**id_shop** --> **Valor = 1**

**id_lang** --> **Valor = 1**

**name** --> **Valor = Raiz**

**link_rewrite** --> **Valor = raiz**

Os outros campos podem ficar em branco